# Get one of multiple iframes with javascript

Tags: javascript

On tracking of an iframe with GA i add to the parent page a script like

```
<script>

setTimeout(function(){ 
  ga(function(tracker) {
    var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
    var frameWindow = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow;

    frameWindow.postMessage(clientId, 'https://parentpage.com'); 
  });
}, 2000); 

</script>
```

As long as there is only one iframe, everything is OK.

But now i have one page with three iframes, with own, different IDs, which should be tracked separately.

How should i address certain iframe to track each iframe separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can select iframes something like this

```js
let iframes=document.querySelectorAll("iframe");


iframes.forEach(elem=>{

console.log(elem.getAttribute("id"))// address your iframe separately here


})
```

```html
<iframe id="one">
</iframe>


<iframe id="two">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all iframes like that:

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for(var i=0;i<frames.length;i++)
{
     //do what ever you want with frames[i]
}
```

alternatively, you can iterate it using forEach:

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
frames.forEach(function(frame){
    //do what ever you want with frame
})
```

Good Luck!